# Only Lights/Camera's origin move instead of all component

Tags: camera, light, origin

I apologize in advance if my problem has already been solved. But i was unable to find a thread relating to my problem.

For some time, when I launch an empty scene in solid mode, I have a strange behavior with my camera and lights. When i move them (grab light : img1 to img2), it affects only the origin (surrounded in blue). The other display don't move and are stuck in at the position 0,0,0 (surrounded in red).

In rendered mode, the light and the camera react in relation with the origin, what seems right.

I was thinking that it was a problem with affect origin in Options. But this option is not checked.

It's just a pain to handle correctly these components.
Have you any idea to get a correct behavior of those items ?

edit : I kept looking and it's also happend for any non-editable objects like force field, speaker, empty ...

[image: Before translation]
[image: After translation]